# How to subscribe to facebook realtime updates of a specific page's conversations

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I'm trying to figure out how to subscribe to realtime updates to a page I have an access_token for (but not my app's page). I'm using the Koala gem and everything seems fine but I can't seem to figure out how to specify which page I want to subscribe to:

```
@updates = Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.new(:app_id => YOUR_APP_ID, :app_access_token => YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN)
@updates.subscribe("page", "conversations", YOUR_CALLBACK_URL, YOUR_VERIFY_TOKEN)
```

the above is the code Koala says to implement but it doesn't say anywhere about how to choose which page we are subscribing to or where to insert the page_access_token.

Even when looking at the facebook [example](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/12/11/real-time-updates-for-page-conversions/) it doesn't have anywhere to enter the page access token.

Where do I specify which facebook page I want so subscribe to?

EDIT: When you subscribe to a "page" "conversations" which page are you subscribing to? All of them associated with a app_access_token? How do I know which pages are associated with the app_access_token?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you linked, there IS some code to specify the Page Access Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/12/11/real-time-updates-for-page-conversions/

Look at the bottom PHP script example:

```
$session = new FacebookSession('<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>');
```

For setting Page Access Tokens, have a look at

- https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page

Comment: yea but how do I pass the page access token to the @updates.subscribe (as shown in the koala gem) like so: @updates.subscribe("user", "first_name, last_name", YOUR_CALLBACK_URL, YOUR_VERIFY_TOKEN)

Comment: nothing in koala realtime updates asks for a token...i'm so confused

Comment: what I'm trying to do is subscribe to another page's conversations (not my own app's page) and I do have that page's access token

Comment: Do you know if you have `read_page_mailboxes` permissions for that page?

Comment: You can only subscribe to a Page's conversations if the Page (respectively it's owner) added your app via `/{page-id}/subscribed_apps` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/subscribed_apps#publish). Concerning permissions, yes, you have to have `read_page_mailboxes` if you want to access the conversations (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/conversations)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have Koala implemented in my app and I've been getting a page's conversation (**not through RealtimeUpdates**) successfully. Here is how I did it -

I added the following to my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'koala'
```

I created a YAML file for facebook credentials -

```
development:
   app_id: <APP ID>
   secret: <APP Secret>
```

I added the following `initializers` under `config/initializers`

1.Facebook initializer as `facebook.rb` -

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

2.Omniauth initializer as `omniauth.rb` -

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
    provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret'], {: scope => 'read_mailbox'}
end
```

The permission `read_mailbox` is key. If you're not sure if you have the `read_mailbox` permission, you might have to request it under `Status and Review` tab under your App's page (see screenshot below) -

[image]

Even though I'm not using `RealTimeUpdates`, I do something like the following to get the conversations -

```
def get_conversations(page_id)
   access_token ||= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK['secret']).get_app_access_token

   graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(access_token)
   @fb_conversations = graph.get_object(page_id + '/conversations')
end
```

Try hitting the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with `{page_id}/conversations` with your access token and see if you're getting an error.